# Add new name automatically in another table whenever a new unique name is added to main table?

Tags: database, ms-access, relationship

Hi I'm new to Access and I'm trying to accomplish the following task:

I maintain a main table with chronological entries of different investment's return on a daily basis with following fields:

> RECORD_DATE, INVESTMENT_NAME, RETURN

Now, I maintain this table by copying a list of investments and their returns from Excel into Access, with the day's date.

So the entries look like:

```
1/1/2013, Manager_A, 10%
1/1/2013, Manager_B, 9%
1/2/2013, Manager_A, 11%
1/2/2013, Manager_B, 8%
```

I also want to maintain a different table describing the Investment

> INVESTMENT_NAME, ASSET_TYPE, MANAGER

I want to be able to add a new entry whenever a new unique manager name shows up in the first table. Of course I will type in the ASSET_TYPE, MANAGER fields myself later.

Is there a way to construct a relationship in Access so that every time when I copy new entries for the day this happens?

Answer (score 0):

As Access does not have triggers you can use Macros. Depending on which version of Access you are using, this link should help you.

http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2009/08/13/access-2010-data-macros-similar-to-triggers.aspx

Comment: That's pretty annoying! I'd think this is a pretty basic feature for a database program.

Comment: If you watch the video its not to much hassle to create them.

Comment: I've done a lot of VBA with Excel. I hope it's easily translatable to Access. Is it possible to keep the INVESTMENT_NAME field unique in the second table and re-add all the entries into the second table every time when the first table is updated, so that only new unique names would create a new row in the second table? I assume this is the method...